# Fedex Tracking API C# not returning useful data

Tags: c#, .net, api, fedex, web-reference

I'm using Fedex supplied example code for C# and I can NOT get it to return any information for active packages.

I've gotten issued a production api key/meter number/password but all it ever tells me is that. 'No information for the following shipments has been recieved...'

I'm using the example program for 'TrackWebServiceClient' verbatim only changing the credentials.

Comment: Of course two minutes later you figure out that the wsdl you get with the examples or even download from them has the url pointed toward teh test services. DOH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the wsdl you got is not pointing toward the test services, but towards the live service instead. ;)